# How to use static entities in Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 10 entities in a database table and I want to have them in my code as well. For example I have `ServiceType`.

I want to be able to create a new object in my C# code by setting the ID of `ServiceType` to a known number. The values of the property fields never change and we wanted to keep them in the code for easier access.

We have created each `ServiceType` object statically:

```
public class ServiceType : IEquatable<ServiceType> {
     public static readonly ServiceType Electricity = new ServiceType { Id = 1, Name = "Electricity", Abbreviation = "E" };
     public static readonly ServiceType Gas = new ServiceType { Id = 2, Name = "Gas", Abbreviation = "G" };
     public static readonly ServiceType Water = new ServiceType { Id = 3, Name = "Water", Abbreviation = "W" };

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is ServiceType))
            return false;
        return ((ServiceType)obj).Id == Id;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id;
    }

    public bool Equals(ServiceType other)
    {
        if ((object)other == null)
        {
            if ((object)this == null)
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        return Id == other.Id;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(ServiceType a, ServiceType b)
    {
        if ((object)a == null)
            return (object)b == null;
        return a.Equals(b);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(ServiceType a, ServiceType b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }
}
```

Now when we have an entity that has a property of type `ServiceType` we want to be able to get or set it using:

```
ServiceType.Electricity
```

But strangely when we get an entity from the database we always have the `ServiceType_ID` to be 0 even thou in the database it says 1. Any suggestions?

Comment: How is the `Id` column being "generated"?  Check out `DatabaseGeneratedOption`.

Comment: there is not enough info to know how strange it is like as you said. You should provide a short snippet of code showing how you used it.